# Universal Mac Electron / Quasar Build Arm64 and X64

Tags: macos, electron, quasar-framework, electron-packager

I have a Quasar / Electron application and I develop it on a MacBook with an Apple M1 Pro Chip.  When I try to run it on my old Mac with an Intel chip, I get an error that says: "You can't open the application because this application is not supported on this Mac."

It runs fine on the Apple M1 Pro MacBook that it's built on.

So I've narrowed this error down to the X64 Mac cannot run the build I did on the Arm64 Mac.

Reading this post: [Electron Apple Silicon Support](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/apple-silicon), I'm attempting to integrate the Universal Option using Electron Packager.  I'm doing this in the Quasar quasar.conf.js file, but I don't know what syntax I should be using.

What I have is the following:

```
packager: {
        OsxUniversal: {
          x64AppPath: '/Users/drive/Projects/Appx64.app',
          arm64AppPath: '/Users/drive/Projects/AppArm64.app',
          outAppPath: '/Users/drive/Projects/AppUniversal.app',
        },
      },
```

But that doesn't change what electron-packager is building, it just builds the same Arm64 application as it does when I do not use those criteria. Neither the X64 or the Universal apps are being built.

I am getting the OsxUniversalOptions from this page: [Namespace electronPackager](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/modules/electronpackager.html#osxuniversaloptions) But since I'm using electrion-packager inside Quasar, I don't know if that is correct.  Apparently it is not, because it's not working.

I would love some help with this. I need my application to be able to run on either the Intel or the Apple M1 Chip Macs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you an use [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/configuration/mac.html):

```
builder: {

  dmg: {
    sign: false,
  },
  mac: {
    target: [
      {
        target: "dmg",
        arch: ["universal"],
      },
    ],
  }
}
```